# get() returned more than one AccessToken

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth, django-rest-framework

I am facing 2 issues here.

1) If user has not old token, a new one should be generated and logged in but it is not happening so.

2)A newly created user when logs in gets 'You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.'

3)old user when trying to login gets an error of get() returned more than one AccessToken -- it returned 8!

Expert might understand from my code

```
class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        access_token = request.GET.get('access_token')
        data = request.data
        print('data',data)
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            if new_data:
                app = Application.objects.get(name="Foodie")
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(username=data['username'])
                    print ('user',user)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return HttpResponse("Can't find this user")
                else:
                    try:
                        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(user=user)
                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        return HttpResponse('Have not set any token')
                    else:
                        access_token.delete()
                new_token = generate_token()
                print('new_token',new_token)
                AccessToken.objects.create(user=user, application=app, expires=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365),token=new_token)
                print('aceess',AccessToken)
                login(request, user)
            return Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']


class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_obj = User(
                username = username,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                email = email
            )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        if user_obj:
            expire_seconds = oauth2_settings.user_settings['ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS']
            scopes = oauth2_settings.user_settings['SCOPES']

            application = Application.objects.get(name="Foodie")
            expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=expire_seconds)
            access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(user=user_obj, 
                                                    application=application,
                                                    token = generate_token(),
                                                    expires=expires, 
                                                    scope=scopes)
        return validated_data
```